# I am looking for the name of a 1990's Windows turn-based strategy game in space

Tags: story-identification, space, video-games

I'm looking for an old game.  It probably ran on Windows 95 but maybe on Windows 3.11. As far as I can remember, it wasn't a DOS game. It might have been a free game from a magazine.

I remember the center of the screen was the space with the planets or ship we were currently managing. As far as remember the main screen couldn't be scrolled horizontal/vertical, but maybe when clicking on a planet or ship it recenter on it.

It was a strategy game in space, where you have star ships, crusaders to visit planets, manage productions on them, etc. Probably a bit of exploration too.

I think it was turn-based because I don't remember any particular movements on screens, just windows opening to manage what to produce / where to go. Sp we don't control any ship directly, but by clicking «go to that planet» on a list (if I remember well)

I m pretty sure some ship where called «Crusader» and maybe it looked like a

I have been looking for it for weeks but all the results I found are wrong.

Does this ring a bell to you?

Edit (to answer questions in comments):

About the interface, as far as remember it couldn't not be scrolled, but maybe when clicking on a planet or ship it recenter on it (similar to star trek USS Enterprise, but with only one motor, and 2D side-view only ).

This is not:

- Imperium Galactica or VGA planets (they seems too recent)
- not mentionned in the reddit comments
- Not Master of Orion (I, II, III), but maybe the interface was a little similar to the 3 (but it was in a window, under Windows OS)
- not Moonbase Commander
- not Ascendancy
- not «Spaceward Ho! » but seems very similar in terms of functionnality
- not Imperium Galactica

Comment: sounds like either Imperium Galactica or VGA planets.

Comment: Was it one of the games mentioned in the comments section of this Reddit post? https://www.reddit.com/r/4Xgaming/comments/3ipgcw/looking_for_a_pc_game_midlate_90s_space_game_with/

Comment: Do you remember the name of the magazine?

Comment: @AJM was "PCJeux" I think (a french one). The the game is in english (and I didn't understood everything well as a teen)

Comment: @Asenar: Did the view stay centered on your current ship/planet, or could you scroll around to view the other planets? Were you directly controlling the ship, or issuing orders?

Comment: @Asenar Was the coverdisk a CD or a floppy? Also, "PCJeux" looks like a French version of PCGamer magazine - same logo, just French text.

Comment: And that word - "crusaders" - you use. Was that specifically what the game called them?

Comment: Moonbase Commander?

Comment: Any chance it is one of the Master of Orion games? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Orion

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Orion_II:_Battle_at_Antares

Comment: I was thinking Ascendancy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascendancy_(video_game)), although it was an MS-DOS game.

Comment: I was thinking of [*Spaceward Ho!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceward_Ho!).

Comment: Or [Imperium Galactica](https://www.myabandonware.com/game/imperium-galactica-btd)

Comment: Hi, sorry everyone, I was quite busy theses weeks and couldn't get time to answers. This is not any of game you proposed here, but thanks for your times and suggestions (I edited my question to add precisions / answers to comments)

Comment: There's a sentence with the end missing: "and maybe it looked like a" - but like a WHAT?

Comment: Also, could the "Crusader" ships have had a different name that sounded like "Crusader"? Like "Cruiser" or "Commander"?

Comment: You say VGA Planets sounds too recent. As its first version was released [in 1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_Planets), I think it's definitely in the right timeframe. As for the "similar to ... USS Enterprise" with only one warp nacelle, look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BEPBwCrZ9k at the 1:26 and 1:30 marks. It shamelessly rips off the USS Defiant (8:19), more Enterprise-y ships after 8:54. For another version, see https://www.donovansvgap.com/clients/wpl35ships.jpg and a DS( ripoff at https://www.donovansvgap.com/clients/wpl35bases.jpg

Comment: There are current versions of VGA Planets still being sold (I think even a phone app), but it was a shareware game in the early 90's.

Comment: I wonder if it might have been Star Atlantis as described in [this Reddit question](https://old.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/comments/14m21bo/dospre_2000_4x_dos_shareware_space_game_called/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly well-known game around that time was *[Stars!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars!)*

> Starting with a small fleet of ships and one or two planets, players develop their empires, meet other races and conquer the galaxy. Stars! games begin with race design, choosing one of 10 primary racial traits, a selection of lesser racial traits, habitability, growth, economic, and technology settings. The graphics are entirely 2D, and consist of the main map view and static pictures of planets, ship hulls and components. Battles consist of moving static icons around a grid. Because of the high level of micromanagement and diplomacy requirements, many games take place over months between players spread across the galaxy.
>
> Players initially send scouts out to scan for suitable planets which later may be colonized and developed, enlarging the player's empire and providing additional resources. As a player's empire expands the player must balance the management of the population, minerals, research, and ship/infrastructure constructions. When other players' races are encountered, a variety of diplomacy options allow for alliances, trading mineral resources or technology, large-scale wars, and even the destruction of other races. If the random events game option is enabled, players will have to contend with (or take advantage of) the Mystery Trader, comet strikes, wormholes, and environmental changes.

It ran from Windows 3.1 onwards, although modern computers typically use DosBox to run it (and there's still a pretty thriving community). There's planetary production, discovery and exploitation of planets, and competition with the other alien races.

[image: Image of the Stars! interface] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Comment: This is not the game, but it seems to be pretty similar to what I m looking for in term of functionnality, but there wasn't anything related to alien or different races.

Comment: Hi again, after some month (and re-reading your answer time to time), maybe it was this game, this is a too old for my memories, so I just validated your answer as it's probably this, and I will try it when I will have time, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be Star General:

- I played it on Windows 95
- It is turn based
- There is a planet view, where you could manage production of units
- There is a space view, where you could steer your ships to other planets/fight other ships

Comment: This is not the game, there wasn't any «planet view» and the interface was «in a window, on windows 95» (maybe I wasn't clear on the first description)

Answer (score 0):

Space Crusade, perhaps? It follows slightly more with your description.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question already has an accepted answer, so if you want to suggest an answer that you believe is better, you need to make a convincing argument that your identification is a better match to the question.  You should [edit] this answer to include as much detail about the game as you can find, focusing on the points that match the question.

Comment: The OP's comments beneath [FuzzyBoots' answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/274568/122024) indicate that they weren't sure that answer was actually correct. Nonetheless, editing this answer to be more specific about how _Space Crusade_ fits the OP's description would help other users decide how likely _this_ answer is to be correct or not.

Comment: I don't think *Space Crusade* is likely to be a good match. I wouldn't really call it a `strategy` game, you're controlling a fairly small number of Space Marines, and there's no "manage production" aspect to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it wasn't that either